# facebook api confusion

Tags: php, facebook

I am coming back to facebook app development after a long time. And I am confused :)
Am I required to use the Graph API or can I still use the REST Api?
Because I am unable to make calls with the old REST api methods.

I am using PHP. Do I need to use the (now) official SDK?

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use the REST API, but they recommend developers to use the new Graph API. I'd be surprised if Facebook doesn't start phasing out the old API soon, and ultimately deprecate it altogether.

You can make API calls to the old REST API with Facebook's new PHP SDK as well, and unlike the old library it doesn't suck.